# Difference between rcptt.ide-2.5.5-N202401071209-win & rcptt.ide-2.5.5-N202401081455-win

Tags: stm32cubeide

1- I want to know the different commit between Difference between rcptt.ide-2.5.5-N202401071209-win & rcptt.ide-2.5.5-N202401081455-win.

I want to know the different commit between Difference between rcptt.ide-2.5.5-N202401071209-win & rcptt.ide-2.5.5-N202401081455-win.

record the last rcptt with the last eclipse 2023-12 (When I integrated the last version eclipse 2023-12 in my application and try to record with last rcptt --> the test fail)